# how to get list of font-family supported by browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [list every font a user's browser can display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368837/list-every-font-a-users-browser-can-display)

I am developing a application where user can select font-family using select box. but I do not know how to get supported font family from a browser.

Is it possible to get list of font-family supported by browser?

If yes how?

Comment: There is no really *good* way to do this. The best I can see is   [list every font a user's browser can display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368837/list-every-font-a-users-browser-can-display)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the fonts that you want, rather than limiting yourself to the crossection of fonts supported by all browsers:

http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/getting_started.html#Quick_Start

Answer (score -1):

[Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) is a great tool JS library for detecting the features the current browser supports. There is a section in there dedicated to font-family support and detection. That would be a good place to start.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP means. Modernizr can detect `font-face` support but that has nothing to do with the list of installed fonts on the client machine

Comment: It sounds like he just wants to see if the selected font is support in the users current browser. "but I do not know how to get supported font family from a browser."

Comment: "get list of font-family supported by browser" doesn't support that IMO

Comment: So that it can be compared with that the user has selected. Not just to have a list, I'm assuming.

Comment: But Modernizr can't help with that, is I think Pekka's point.