# About displaying all fonts in dropdown box

Tags: php, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [list every font a user's browser can display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368837/list-every-font-a-users-browser-can-display)

I want to display all the fonts in my system in dropdown box how can i do this 
Till now i was just specifying the fonts name manually..

```
<select id="family" name="family">
<option>Verdana</option>
<option>Arial</option>
<option>Helvetica</option>
<option>Times New Roman</option>
<option>Comic Sans MS</option>
</select>
```

Comment: And let us know what you understand by 'my system'. Do you want to display all fonts of your browser?

Comment: which are all fonts are there in any system if i give this application to any one if they open this the dropdown list should contain all the fonts downloaded or present in their system

Comment: "If I give this application to anyone"... you mean if someone uses the php code in their own server, it should display the information from the browser? Because **the fonts available depend on the browser, not on the web server**.

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs on the server. This would have to be done client side, so you would need to use Flash or Silverlight (Which runs on the clients machine).