# Browser font support

Tags: javascript, fonts

Can JavaScript (or something else) tell me what fonts my browser supports out of the box, without loading external font files?

I would like to programmatically generate a list of the installed fonts on my Browser.

(In the Chrome dev tools, under the "Elements" pane, if one does `Ctrl + Click` inside a custom CSS property with empty value, it will tell you the list of acceptable values for that property. E.g., for the CSS property `display` it will tell you `inline`, `inline-block`, `inline-table`, etc. Unfortunately, the list for `font-family` doesn't contain the available fonts.)

Comment: This might help, however not sure if it is what you need: http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368837/list-every-font-a-users-browser-can-display duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Using JavaScript](http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect), given a font name one can test if the corresponding font is installed. That's not good enough.

[Using Flash](http://hasseg.org/blog/post/526/getting-a-list-of-installed-fonts-with-flash-and-javascript/), one can retrieve the full list of fonts. There is a nice demo [here](http://font-detect.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html).

Comment: The Flash method does not work in IE 11, as you can see in that demo.