# Let the user choose a font among fonts available in his own computer

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, fonts

Is there a way to let the user choose a font from their own computer with Javascript?

Sorry if this sounds a bit basic, but I googled for it and all I found was hundreds of thousands of tutorials on how to use `style.fontFamily`. That, however, is not what my problem is. I already know how to set a font.

I want to allow the user to set a certain piece of text to a certain font they can choose themselves. Like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eTF93/1/).

```html
<p>
   Type a font name: <input id="font" /> and click
   <button type="button" id="button">here</button>
</p>
<p id="example">
   And this is the text that will be displayed in the chosen font.
</p>
```

```javascript
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
 document.getElementById('example').style.fontFamily =
  document.getElementById('font').value;
};
```

Except I want the input to have a `datalist` that contains the font names on the user's computer. Or it can be a `select`.

Some libraries look promising at first sight, such as ["JQuery Font Chooser"](https://github.com/CD1212/jQuery-Font-Chooser), but that too uses a preset list instead of using the actually available fonts.

By now it almost looks as if fetching font names from the client computer is not possible...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368837/list-every-font-a-users-browser-can-display

Comment: would they have to upload their own font file, like a .ttf?

Comment: @DeclanCook Oh, I see. Yes, this is a duplicate, and apparently I used the wrong search terms.

Comment: @JohnnyRockex No, I just mean the installed fonts. You know, like you get in your browsers preferences window, where you choose which font you want to use for serif, sans-serif etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [list every font a user's browser can display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368837/list-every-font-a-users-browser-can-display)

Comment: @André Yes, but the same link was already posted 9 years ago by Declan Cook, above.

Comment: And after 9 years this still hasn't been marked as a duplicate.