# how to get whole list of font family in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I'm using fabric.js in my site. suppose if I need to add any text in canvas, I write - like-

```
var text1 = new fabric.Text('Fabric', {
  left: 90,
  top: 570,
  angle: -5,
  fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
  fontSize: 20,
  fill: 'red'
})
```

but I need all available fonts (like - times new roman, Helvetica) in a list so that I can select the font at run time, I tried to google it but I got nothing.
I wonder if anybody help me.
Thank in advance.

Comment: This is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368837/list-every-font-a-users-browser-can-display. In short, you can't do it in pure JavaScript. Here's a Flash + JS solution: https://github.com/gabriel/font-detect-js.

Comment: dear, I don't want to detect any font, I need the list of fonts provided by fabric.js.

Comment: fabric.js it's not a magic wand, it doesn't provide any font, it's a simple JS library to edit HTML5 canvas elements. And in canvas you can change the font by setting the [`font`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font) property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas

Answer (score 1):

fabricjs doens't provide any fonts for you. Instead, it uses a html5 canvas and therefore have the font the browser provides for you.

If you need to list available fonts during runtime you can test out the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368837/list-every-font-a-users-browser-can-display).

Of you can import you own using [font-face](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fontface).