# Fabric Js : How to get list of default supported fontFamily?

Tags: fonts, fabricjs

I am working with **Fabric Text**. I need a lot of fonts for my application. I am intending to **apply custom font** for those, which are not not supported by default.That's why i need the **default supported font list**. How can i get them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you cannot get the list of fonts. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22787104/how-to-get-whole-list-of-font-family-in-fabric-js). But if you want to use your custom fonts than it is possible. Have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21010750/load-custom-font-for-fabric-js) to know how to use custom fonts in fabricjs

Comment: Fabric js support all fonts html5 canvas does. Is it? I have no issue with implementing custom font.

Comment: I agree with the response @HarshMakani.  But to clarify a bit as to why the list of fonts is not available is because the "list" would depend on the default fonts available to a particular browser/operating system combination of the user.  Because this combination set is so vast and unpredictable it's really hard to put out a specific list.  This link does list some of the common options however.  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp