# javascript how detect system fonts (all fonts that exists in system)

Tags: javascript, fonts

Trying to get system fonts to use as part of browser fingerprint (like here https://panopticlick.eff.org/index.php?action=log&js=yes)

Searching Google found 2 options

http://hasseg.org/blog/post/526/getting-a-list-of-installed-fonts-with-flash-and-javascript/

But here http://hasseg.org/stuff/fontList/example.html see `Listing not done yet... (make sure Javascript and Flash are enabled)`. So for all visitors that have not enabled JavaScript/Flash result would be the same. In https://panopticlick.eff.org/index.php?action=log&js=yes see `No Flash or Java fonts detected`. Also in comments below https://stackoverflow.com/a/3368858/2118559 read that Flash not good option. And for me seems very difficult how to implement.

Another option to use http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect/. Seems very simple and understandable. But it detect only one particular font. So i must create/define some array of fonts (name each font) and loop through array. For example here http://www.myfonts.com/search/is_webfont%3Atrue/fonts/ see that 22,652 fonts available... Loop through 22,652 fonts. Not good option

Any ideas how to get list of existing system fonts?

Comment: AFAIK there's no way in Javascript to query the host system for system-related data of any kind. Why do you need to know what's installed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [list every font a user's browser can display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368837/list-every-font-a-users-browser-can-display)

Comment: I need to use as part of browser fingerprint

Comment: @spender I know link you mention. I even in my question wrote about the answer and placed link. And read about the two options, i mentioned. My question is: is there any other option. Because the 2 options i know, are not very suitable. Seems no other options. May be to use javascript to loop through most common system fonts

Comment: @Andris, did you find any solution about that?