# How to convert SVG text element with @font-face to canvas using html2canvas.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, font-face, html2canvas

I'm trying to use `html2canvas.js` (https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to take screenshots with JavaScript. However, I have a problem when the page contains SVG text elements.

As you can see on the screenshots below, the text element is duplicated (and only one of the copies keep the right font family).

**Original body**
[image: Original body: one text element]

**Canvas copy**
[image: Canvas copy: two text elements]

Here is my code

**HTML**

```html
<svg width="600" height="200" style="background-color:lightblue;">
  <text transform="translate(100, 100)" style="font-size:60px; font-family: 'Oswald'">Hello world</text>
</svg>

<br/>
<button id="createCanvasButton">Create canvas !</button>
```

**CSS**

```css
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);
```

**JS**

```js
$('#createCanvasButton').on('click', function() {
  html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  });
});
```

**jsFiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/AndreLovichi/571t86u4/

**Note**
I've been looking for a similar issue, and I've found this one: [SVG Text attribute is doubling - HTML2CANVAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597242/svg-text-attribute-is-doubling-html2canvas).
However, the patch on `NodeParser.prototype.getChildren` didn't work for me: the remaining text element had the wrong font family.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

## note

`I updated on your code. Please add font base64 in svg. Maybe I answered too late ：），This is the first answer I use stackoverflow
The font need change dataURI insert in SVG`

## JS

```js
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("get", './xxx/demo.woff');
request.responseType = "blob";
request.onloadend = () => { let fontDemoDataURI = reader.result }
```

## html

```html
    <svg>
         <style>
          @font-face {
          font-family: 'Oswald';
              src: url(data:application/font-woff;base64,d09GRgABAAAAOtXY........ED==);
          </style>
    </svg>
```

## LINKS

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfEQs.png)

https://jsfiddle.net/571t86u4/93/

Comment: Can you provide some more detail about how this answers the original question.