# is it possible to get available fonts list supported by browser in jsp using request object?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I would like to show list of the fonts supported by client browser in a combo list instead of adding fonts manually to the combo. 
Is it possible to get the list, if yes how to achive this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not in JSP, but client-side (and then if you really need it on the server, you could send this data) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368837/list-every-font-a-users-browser-can-display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot list the font using request object in JSP.
You can get system supported fonts using GraphicsEnvironment class