# Is it possible for front-end to know the local supported font-family?

Tags: html, web, fonts, operating-system

I know we could define `@fontface` to download web-font. However, this could be problematic especially for chinese fonts due to its large size.

Yet in modern system, it's likely that it already installed some pre-set fonts. For example, a Windows might already installed fonts like SimHei, SimSun, NSimSun, FangSong, KaiTi, a Mac might installed fonts like Hiragino Sans GB, STHeiti Light, STHeiti, STKaiti.

So is it possible for a web-app to know what font this system had installed?

Comment: @font-face for CJKV is perfectly fine, as long as you throw a 12MB font at people: you combine subsetting (e.g. don't include glyphs your content doesn't even use), and you use `woff2` so you can serve the font split up into segments based on page coverage. If 20 of your pages only use 400 characters, and a further 2 pages use 900 each, then you split your `woff2` into two (or more) sets such that most pages won't ever need to load all of those, because their content won't require it.

Comment: How about a case that you are unsure what content the app will require? For example, to enable the user to be able to enjoy the same experience regardless whatever epub books he opened?

Comment: Who said anything about epub. Your tags say "html" and "web", neither of those things are epub related.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here it was the closed I could find (*it may not be performant*):

[list every font a user's browser can display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368837/list-every-font-a-users-browser-can-display/3368855#3368855)

Goodluck