# How can I detect if the user has a specific font installed?

Tags: javascript, web, fonts

Is there a function in JavaScript that tells me if a specific font is installed?

If not, how could I check it then?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368837/list-every-font-a-users-browser-can-display/3368855#3368855

Comment: Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62399430/10732434). It uses `document.fonts.entries()` to look up the fonts.

Comment: Thanks for your help!